# Angular 5 starter - incorrect image (png/jpg/gif) files generation (aot build)

Tags: angular

i am working on angular 5 Project. after build the project then i got some issue are as mention below.

Before Build

menu.component.css

```
.col ul li a span {
     background-image:url("../../../assets/images_theme/product_image/sprite.png");
}
```

aot build

```
.col[_ngcontent-c4] ul[_ngcontent-c4] li[_ngcontent-c4] a[_ngcontent-c4] span[_ngcontent-c4] {
background-image: url(sprite.b1e865f878c33aa6c5cc.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Files are bundled, meaning the route is starting from `index.html`. Try this :

```
background-image:url("assets/images_theme/product_image/sprite.png");
```